# How do I change the keyboard shortcut to create new file or folder in the Project view in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ in the Project tool window with default keybindings one can create a new item (in the folder selected) with <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>INSERT</kbd>.

I have selected the VS Code keymap but this keyboard shortcut hasn't changed. How do I change it so I can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> instead?

Using IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.2 Ultimate. In keymap settings I have tried `Find Actions by Shortcut` and searched for all actions with <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>INSERT</kbd> shortcut and none of them seems right; none of them seemingly applies to the Project view.

Answer (score 1):

Found a nearly identical dialogue called "New in This Directory" which allows to create new files and folders in the Project view. In Keymap settings it can be found under the folder "Other".